# Reading part of a file in C using fread() and fseek()

Tags: c, memory, file-io, malloc, fread

I'm trying to read a file into a buffer in blocks of size `BLOCK_SIZE` (currently equal to `1000 unsigned chars`). My code initially finds the number of blocks it will have to read in order to read the entire file (usually 2-4), then iterates through a for loop reading the file (ignore the "`+17+filenamesize`" stuff, that is all needed for later in the program.

However, only on the first time, when `j=1`, does it actually put data into the `buf` array. In other cases, when `j != 1`, `strlen(buf)` returns **0**.

I think the problem is either with the use of `fseek()` to seek to the second part of a file before reading it or a memory allocation issue.

Any help would be appreciated for getting it to read the `1000-1999`<sup>th</sup> chars of the file into the `buf` array.

Attached is the relevant part of the code:

```
unsigned char *buf;
source = fopen(localpath,"r");
temp = filesize / BLOCK_SIZE + 1;

for (j=1; j <= temp; j++) {
  if (j == 1) {
     buf = (unsigned char *) malloc((sizeof(unsigned char)) * (BLOCK_SIZE + 17 + filenamesize));
     fread(buf+17+filenamesize, sizeof(unsigned char), BLOCK_SIZE, source);
   } else if (j == temp) {
     buf = (unsigned char *) malloc((sizeof(unsigned char)) * (filesize + 5 - BLOCK_SIZE*(j-1)));
     fseek(source, BLOCK_SIZE*(j-1), SEEK_SET); // off by one warning
     fread(buf+5, sizeof(unsigned char), filesize - BLOCK_SIZE*(j-1), source);
   } else {
     buf = (unsigned char *) malloc((sizeof(unsigned char)) * (5+BLOCK_SIZE*(j-1)));
     fseek(source, BLOCK_SIZE*(j-1), SEEK_SET); // off by one warning
     fread(buf+5, sizeof(unsigned char), BLOCK_SIZE, source);
   }
   // do stuff with buf here

   buf = "";
   free(buf);
}
```

Comment: By the way - is there really ANY reason you use fseek? Your current code could just skill all the fseek altogether and live happier.

Comment: The file is ASCII. You're right, I probably don't need to use fseek. fread will just leave the file pointer where it left off from reading, right?

Comment: @EFraim: Great, thank you. I've removed those and it works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend checking the results of [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/) and [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/).  In particular, make sure fseek is returning 0 - if it's not, this may be the entire problem.

Provided that fseek is succeeding, fread should tell you the total number of bytes read.

Also, strlen is not necessarily a valid thing to use, since it's going to assume that this is a null terminated string.  If the first character you read is a 0 byte, strlen will return 0.  You're not treating this as a null terminated string (you aren't allocating enough space for teh null terminator - just exactly what's needed to fit your binary data), so strlen is probably inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem, that the string started with null characters. That has been fixed, and I also made it null-terminated, and now it is working fine!

Answer (score 2):

The line `buf = "";` looks like a bug to me. This will set the pointer buf to a constant string which you also try to `free()` on the next line. I would just skip this line.

You also seem to read into the buffer with some offsets. ie +5 in the two later cases. The first part in the buffer will then be undefined, see man page for `malloc`. So a `strlen(buf)` feels undefined for me.

Comment: So there is a leak after all. Only the "" string is freed. I think that can crash.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using fseek at all?  The whole notion of "first check how big the file is to determine how many times to read a block" is fundamentally flawed.  You should simply read data until there is no more data left, for example:

```
while( BLOCK_SIZE == ( read_count = fread( buf, sizeof *buf, count, source ))
    do_stuff_with_buf( buf, read_count );

if( ferror( source ))
    /* Handle error */;
```

(This example will never call do_stuff_with_buf() on a short read, but that is a trivial modification.)

Answer (score 0):

srtlen returns the length of a string (number of bytes before the first 0 byte). If buf[0] is 0 it returns 0. Use the return value of the fread to determine how many bytes are actually read.

You also have memory leak. You malloc in every loop iteration but only free once at the end.

Comment: There is a leak - he assigns buf to a static pointer ("") and then tries to free() it. That shouldn't be working in the first place.